# CropperJs image is tiny in Vue but after editing it gets back to normal size

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js, cropperjs

This is a very strange behavior and I don't know what to make of it, I'm building a website for cropping images using Vue.js and CropperJs, on homepage users select the image they want to crop and click on 'Continue', next page shows a component called `ImageCropper.vue`, the canvas and everything is displayed successfully but it's tiny, but let's say I edit the html, even if I add just a blank line, the image gets back to the size it should be (I don't have a predefined size for it, so it just takes 100% of the width of the container and height is auto, I suppose.)

`ImageCropper.vue`

```
<template>
    <div class="image-container">
        <img ref="image" :src="source">

    </div>
</template>

<script>
import Cropper from 'cropperjs'

export default {
    name: "ImageCropper",
    props: ["source"],

    data() {
        return {
            cropper: null,
            imageElement: null
        }
    },

    mounted() {
        this.imageElement = this.$refs.image
        this.cropper = new Cropper(this.imageElement, {
                aspectRatio: 1 
        })

    }
}
</script>
```

Before editing template: [image: before editing]

After editing it (just added a blank line): [image]

I tried styling it with css but none seem to have effect on it, maybe there's something wrong with the way I use vue? This is Vue with Vuetify, if that matters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was that cropper got initialized while its container was not visible, as I was using vuetify's stepper, the cropping part came after user clicked on "continue", before that is had `display: none`, when I edited it though, it was visible and cropper was being re-initialized whilst its container was visible thus resulting in it rendering normally (Hot reloading with vue cli). I don't know what exactly is the cause of this but I am pretty certain it's not coding error on my side, maybe cropperjs and vuetify's stepper don't work well together. I solved it by adding `continueClicked` to my Vuex state and set default to false, then added @click listener to initial Continue button which sets the `continueClicked` in Vuex to true, added `v-if="continueClicked"` directive to the `ImageCropper.vue` component, like so:
`<ImageCropper v-if="continueClicked" />`, this way when the Continue button is clicked and `continueClicked` is set to true, cropper gets rendered when its container is visible.

Answer (score -1):

There is a wrapper available for this, its vue-cropperjs, check it out.

```
<template>
 <div>
   <vue-cropper ref="cropper" :src="source" alt="Source Image"></vue-cropper>
   <v-btn @click="save">Save</v-btn>
 </div>
</template>
<script>
  import VueCropper from 'vue-cropperjs';
  import 'cropperjs/dist/cropper.css';

  export default{
    name: "ImageCropper",
    components: {
            VueCropper
    },
    methods: {
      save: function(){
        this.$refs.cropper.getCroppedCanvas().toBlob((blob) => {

          //Do anything with the blob, for eg: attach to form data and send to serve
          const formData = new FormData();
          formData.append("type", "profile");
          formData.append('file', blob, this.fileName);

        });
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: I used that as well, I got same results.